# Unable to register a module in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple frontend application, which can be found [here](https://github.com/chupacabra007/otus/tree/master/frontend/app). In my index file I load app.js first and then authentication.js service:

```
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/authentication.js"></script>
```

Authentication module can be found in `scripts/services/authentication.js` file and looks like so:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('Authentication')

.factory('AuthenticationService',
    ['$http', '$rootScope', 
     function ($http, $rootScope) {
        var service = {};

        service.Login = function (username, password) {
            $http.post('/users/authenticate', { username: username, password: password })
                .success(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                });
        };

        service.SetCredentials = function (token) {
            $rootScope.localStorage.setItem('token', token);            
            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token; // jshint ignore:line
        };

        service.ClearCredentials = function () {
            $rootScope.removeItem('toke');
            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ';
        };

        return service;
}]);
```

I'm extremely new to AngularJS and I'm just following this [tutorial](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/03/10/angularjs-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial). The problem I get, when I run my application is:

> Module 'Authentication' is not available. You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it...

Comment: I tried to swap app.js and authentication.js in index.html file, but got `Module frontendApp is not available`. I really wonder, why such a simple code, based on tutorials does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
angular.module('Authentication')
```

should be

```
angular.module('app')
```

Because you try to load two module in same file but this possible even though according to your tutorial mention here that kind of thing couldn't do so change  `Authentication` to `app`.

Comment: I will check it in a second!

Comment: Oh, sorry! Thank you, miss!